# How to remove the vertical header in QStandardItemModel?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview, qstandarditemmodel

I have created a table using `QTableView` and a `QStandardItem` widget. How to remove the vertical header from `QStandardItemModel`?

Comment: You don't remove it from the model, you hide it in the view

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use the header's `hide()` method:

```cpp
QTableView * view = new QTableView();
view->verticalHeader()->hide();
```

Don't forget to `#include <QHeaderView>`.

Comment: For `QTreeView`, use `treeView->header()->hide()`